# How to create dynamic property in __init__

Tags: python

I have a simple scenario. I pass a kwarg `prop_name` and `prop_func` into my class init that I want to turn into property such as:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, prop_name=None, prop_func=None, **kwargs):
        if prop_name is not None and prop_func is not None:
            setattr(self, prop_name, property(prop_func))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Why cannot I then do something like:

```
a = A(prop_name='some_name', prop_func=lambda _: 1)
print(a.some_name)
```

The result is:

```
>>> <property object at 0x7feb3f27cf98>
```

However, this works:

```
class A:
    some_name = property(lambda _: 1)

a = A()
print(a.some_name)

>>> 1
```

EDIT: Possible workaround to get the same bahaviour. Please correct if there is any practical difference.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args, prop_name=None, prop_func=None, **kwargs):
        self._prop_name = prop_name
        self._prop_func = prop_func

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item == self._prop_name:
            return self._prop_func(self)  # this solution does not accept arguments
        super().__getattr__(self, item)

a = A(prop_name='some_name', prop_func=lambda _: 1)
print(a.some_name)
>>> 1
```

EDIT 2: Explanation of why this behaviour solution is required.
This behaviour is supposed to happen in a `Mixin` for a django view. The goal is to be able to dynamically create related views between related objects. For example:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    ... some attributes ...


class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    .... some attributes ...
```

It would be very nice if, directly in the view, we could refer to the City's object generically like so:

```
self.parent
```

I've done this in the Mixin that is now shown here, it's way out of scope. However, for convenience sake, it would also be nice if we could refer to this `parent` object directly as the field name itself, ie:

```
self.continent # basically just calls self.parent
```

This makes the code very intuitive to read. An example of a very simplified view:

```
class CountryDetailView(ParentMixin, DetailView):
    model = Country
    parent_model = Continent

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['continent'] = self.continent  # equivalent to self.parent
        return context
```

Comment: Where have you even defined the `some_name` attribute in your class definition?? What happens when you try `print(a.prop_name)`?

Comment: @Adi219 He shows the output of when he prints it

Comment: If you remove the `property` wrapping around `prop_func` and give it any arguments, for example `prop_func(1)` it sets the value correctly.

Comment: @chrisz No, he's showing the output of `print(a.some_name)`, which isn't defined...

Comment: @Adi219 `prop_name` is a parameter name, not an attribute of `A`

Comment: You can't add properties to instances, [only classes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: @chrisz yes, but then the value is calculated at `__init__` and not when it is called. I need to value to be actually calculated (with the function) when it is called, not just set a value.

Comment: @Adi219 `some_name` does not need a definition, it is the indented name for the property. Calling `a.prop_name` does not make sense as the `property` is set to be accessed by `a.some_name` in the example I've provided.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what would be the best workaround to this then? Saving `prop_name` and `prop_func` to `self` in `__init__` and then make a `__getattr__` for this case? (I'll update my question with this possible solution for you to see)

Comment: As a general rule, all instances of the same class should support the same interface. What is your reason for violating this principle?

Comment: @chepner There is a reason for this that would take longer to explain than the comment allows. I'll write an explanation to the original question description.